# Get multiple tags by slug

Tags: tags

The following code works fine for me:

```
$term = get_term_by('slug', ‘foo’, 'post_tag');       
$args = array ( 
  'posts_per_page' => 5, 
  'paged' => $paged,
  'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ,
  'tag__not_in' => $term
);
```

I'd now like to `get_term_by` multiple tags, e.g., 'foo' and 'bar' (I'm trying to display all posts *except* those tagged 'foo' or 'bar').

I realize this is probably elementary, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a better way than in my previous answer:

First you need to set up an array containing the slugs of the tags you want to exclude. Then loop over that array, and on each term, use `get_term_by()` to get the tag, saving its ID to another array. That is what you can pass through to your query.

```
$tag_slugs = array(
    'foo',
    'bar',
);

$tag_ids = array();
foreach( $tag_slugs as $slug ) {
    $tag = get_term_by( 'slug', $slug, 'post_tag' );
    $tag_ids[] = $tag->term_id;
}

$args = array ( 
  'posts_per_page' => 5, 
  'paged'          => $paged,
  'post__not_in'   => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
  'tag__not_in'    => $tag_ids,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_term_by()` can only retrieve a single term. Try using `get_terms()` instead. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response, but even with get_terms, I'm still uncertain how to address multiple tags slugs.

Comment: I just realized that's not the best way... see my new answer below. :)

Comment: Thanks very much, Peter! This works great, and it's very understandable!

Comment: Great! Please don't forget to mark my answer above (the one you're referring to) as "accepted". :)